# Js syntax (?) Error

Tags: javascript, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

What is my mistake there?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(){
        var GetaName = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : $('a[name ='+GetaName[1]+']').offset().top},1000);
    });
});
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Does `$('a[name ='+GetaName[1]+']')` return anything?

Comment: It is not able to recognize $('a[name ='+GetaName[1]+']')

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference but try removing the space before the `=`, you may also want to add a `e.preventDefault()` to your click event otherwise your page will jump to anything with that id

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong selector built, the value of the element `name` must be in the double quotes. So right code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(){
        var GetaName = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : $('a[name="'+GetaName[1]+'"]').offset().top},1000);
    });
});
```

All above is valid if the page contains element with the selector `'a[name="'+GetaName[1]+'"]'`

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work.. look at this link http://www.backlabel.com/48-dreamy and try to enter in a product (WITH FIREFOX) the error displayed still there..

Comment: Links there have no hash attribute in their hrefs, so `GettaName[1]` is empty string and of course jQuery can not find it

Comment: and what i need to do?